# Map output format is different from reduce output format in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, output

I want output of Map to be **SequenceFileOutputFormat**, and final output of reduce to be **TextOutputFormat**.

job configuration allows to specify **setOutputFormatClass** only

How can I set different output formats for map and reduce stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can specify different output formats for the mapper and reducer, just for the overall job. One option you could try, depending on your processing, you could have a single job output the file in the SequenceFileOutputFormat and then another job that reads and processes it to turn it in to the TextOutputFormat.

Answer (score 0):

Job configuration also allows to specify output of Map using setMapOutputKeyClass and setMapOutputValueClass methods of [Job class](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/) in hadoop mapreduce package

Comment: I need to have different **file** output formats, not just key/value.